# How do I remove Chinese characters from string B whenever they occur in string A, while preserving the order?

Tags: text-processing, unicode

I have some long strings of Chinese characters, but for the sake of the question, let's suppose they are:

```
啊爱好情人心安静排全装按照八把握爸吧白菜酒色夭百班长板
```

and

```
阿姨啊挨打矮小爱国护安检慰置岸边上按摩时案子暗示巴士拔
```

The first string lists all of the "easy" Chinese characters.  The second string lists all "easy" and "intermediate" Chinese characters, but I only want the "intermediate" Chinese characters: I want to delete the "easy" characters from the second string.

E.g. after editing, the second string will not contain 啊 nor 爱 (and perhaps more deletions) since they both occur in the first string.

**Question**: How do I remove Chinese characters from string B whenever they occur in string A, while preserving the order?

I feel like this should be solvable with `awk` or `sed` or something; I don't mind.  It looks like I could convert these strings to two text files, and use any one of the commands in [How to remove the lines which appear on file B from another file A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/how-to-remove-the-lines-which-appear-on-file-b-from-another-file-a)  However, I'd rather do it without creating auxiliary files.

It's also important to retain the order of the characters in the strings.

Answer (score 1):

In shells that allow the syntax `${parameter/pattern/string}` (ksh,bash,zsh) you can do:

```
$ easy='啊爱好情人心安静排全装按照八把握爸吧白菜酒色夭百班长板'
$ intermediate='阿姨啊挨打矮小爱国护安检慰置岸边上按摩时案子暗示巴士拔'

$ echo "${intermediate//[$easy]/}" 
阿姨挨打矮小国护检慰置岸边上摩时案子暗示巴士拔
```

That is based on a regex-like selection of characters `[…]`.
All individual characters in `intermediate` that also exist in `easy` will be erased.

An equivalent that is independent of the shell may be:

```
$ echo "$intermediate" | sed 's/['"$easy"']//g'

阿姨挨打矮小国护检慰置岸边上摩时案子暗示巴士拔
```

Answer (score 1):

**using Raku (née Perl6)**

Raku was designed from the ground-up to handle Unicode gracefully. First example of each pair below generally from the Raku docs; second example of each pair adapted to solve with your particular Chinese strings:

```
$ echo "a123b123c" | raku -pe 'tr:d/123//;'
abc
$ echo "阿姨啊挨打矮小爱国护安检慰置岸边上按摩时案子暗示巴士拔" | raku -pe 'tr:d/啊爱好情人心安静排全装按照八把握爸吧白菜酒色夭百班长板//;'
阿姨挨打矮小国护检慰置岸边上摩时案子暗示巴士拔
```

OR

```
$ echo "a123b123c" | raku -pe '.=trans("123" => "");'
abc
$ echo "阿姨啊挨打矮小爱国护安检慰置岸边上按摩时案子暗示巴士拔" | raku -pe '.=trans("啊爱好情人心安静排全装按照八把握爸吧白菜酒色夭百班长板" => "");'
阿姨挨打矮小国护检慰置岸边上摩时案子暗示巴士拔
```

The `-pe` command-line flags instruct Raku to take input linewise and autoprint the return value(s). There are minor differences between the `tr///` operator and the `trans()` routine. Docs below, HTH.

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#tr///_in-place_transliteration
https://docs.raku.org/routine/trans
https://raku.org/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  It may not be the best solution, but it works:

```
echo 阿姨啊挨打矮小爱国护安检慰置岸边上按摩时案子暗示巴士拔 | sed -e "s/.\{1\}/&\n/g" | awk -v pat="啊爱好情人心安静排全装按照八把握爸吧白菜酒色夭百班长板" 'pat ~ $0' | tr -d '\n'
```

Explanation:

- `echo 阿姨啊挨打矮小爱国护安检慰置岸边上按摩时案子暗示巴士拔` is a way to pipe the second string as input
- `sed -e "s/.\{1\}/&\n/g"` adds a newline after each character
- `awk -v pat="啊爱好情人心安静排全装按照八把握爸吧白菜酒色夭百班长板" 'pat !~ $0'` prints only the characters that do not occur in `pat` (the first string)
- `tr -d '\n'` gets rid of all the newlines

It gives the output

```
阿姨挨打矮小国护检慰置岸边上摩时案子暗示巴士拔
```

and removes the characters 啊, 爱, 安, and 按.